# Update array object value

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to update a array object value , I have a object name `totaldays` value is `0` . When I button  click the value will `+1`. Example now `"totaldays":0` , when click `"totaldays":1`

```js
var checkin_status = [
{"startdate":"2015-01-08",
"totaldays":0,
"roadmap":[ 
   
   {"gifttype":"stars","quantity":100,"day":1},
   {"gifttype":"stars","quantity":500,"day":3},
   {"gifttype":"stars","quantity":1000,"day":10},
   {"gifttype":"stars","quantity":1200,"day":20},
   {"gifttype":"stars","quantity":2200,"day":30},
   
    ]

}];


clickforfun(checkin_status);

function clickforfun(){
      var button = "<input type='button' id='click_button' class='click_button' value='Click me now' />"
 
     $("#call_button").append(button);
 
     $("#click_button").click(function(){
         checkin_status[0].totaldays + 1;
     });
 console.log(checkin_status[0].totaldays); // now should be 1 ?
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="call_button"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

wrong click event declaration and change `checkin_status[0].totaldays + 1;` to `checkin_status[0].totaldays += 1;` try this:-

```
 $("#click_button").click(function(){
     checkin_status[0].totaldays += 1;
     clickforfun(checkin_status);
 });

function clickforfun(){   
 console.log(checkin_status[0].totaldays); // now should be 1 ?
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8wcs7o5n/)

Comment: I have edited some code from my question, if the button is append can I add the click event into the function with `checkin_status[0].totaldays += 1;` ?

Comment: you should not do that because every time you call the function click event will bind. For exp if you click one time on button next time it will fire two time and so on check here http://jsfiddle.net/lastuser/8wcs7o5n/1/

Comment: But my button really need to be append inside function, is there any other way to do this ?

Comment: do you need only one button to append? may be this will help http://jsfiddle.net/lastuser/8wcs7o5n/2/

Comment: it update object value  try to alert objcet check this http://jsfiddle.net/lastuser/8wcs7o5n/3/  check the first element of object

Comment: on button click you are not calling function again so its not updation value of lable http://jsfiddle.net/lastuser/8wcs7o5n/5/

Answer (score 0):

Assign the value back

```
$(".click_button").click(function(){
    checkin_status[0].totaldays += 1; // +=, not just +
});
```

Which is shorthand to

```
$(".click_button").click(function(){
    checkin_status[0].totaldays = checkin_status[0].totaldays + 1; // +=, not just +
});
```